# How to scrape multiple pages with the same URL - Python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/en/list/transaction?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnbmaBhD-ARIsAGTPcfVae1prjf_9aKh0dbnaBbzYvi3VhKn4qEXDAQJMS6ZvOiet8GLqzaAaAqH_EALw_wcB&q=3qoOuFNgwUeioKQCtZ9KFA

I'm trying to web scrape a table with Python and I want to scrape all data in 417 pages in this website.  Since the web_url does not change when I click next page, I cannot just iterate over different url with ?page=[1,2,3,4] etc...

The desire outcome is to get all data from all 417 pages, since all 417 pages may be a lot, to simplify let's say getting data for more than just data from page 1, ex: both first and second pages..

I've tried both methods
(1) scraping from page elements with Beautiful Soup & Requests and
(2) directly from the webpage api_url found in Network
but both of the methods failed to find data in all pages ... I'm not sure which part I'm doing it wrong, my guess was the url has some JS controlling which page's data was sent to the api but I'm not sure what to do to simulate this process :(

Below are codes for above method

---

Method 1

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json



web_url = 'https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/en/list/transaction?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnbmaBhD-ARIsAGTPcfVae1prjf_9aKh0dbnaBbzYvi3VhKn4qEXDAQJMS6ZvOiet8GLqzaAaAqH_EALw_wcB&q=3qoOuFNgwUeioKQCtZ9KFA'
data = {"name": "Value"}

r = requests.get(
    web_url
)

print(f'status: {r.status_code}')

if r.status_code == 200:    raw_data = BeautifulSoup( r.content , 'html.parser' )
    

table_content = raw_data.find_all( 'div' , {'class':'cv-structured-list-item cv-structured-list-item--standard bx--structured-list-row'} )
print(len(table_content))
```

Method 2

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

web_url = 'https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/api/Transaction/Search'

_header = {'lang':'en',"postType":"Both","day":"Day1095","sort":"InsOrRegDate","order":"Descending","size":'24',"offset":'24',"pageSource":"search","gclid":"Cj0KCQjwnbmaBhD-ARIsAGTPcfVae1prjf_9aKh0dbnaBbzYvi3VhKn4qEXDAQJMS6ZvOiet8GLqzaAaAqH_EALw_wcB","q":"3qoOuFNgwUeioKQCtZ9KFA"}
_data = {"name":"Value"}

req = requests.post( web_url , headers =_header , json = _data)

print(f'Status Code: {req.status_code}')

if req.status_code==200:    data = json.loads(req.content)['data']

print( len(data) )

print(data[0].get('displayText').get('addr'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the pagination from payload data following the `offset` key as data is loaded from API as POST method as json format.

**Example:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url= 'https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/api/Transaction/Search'
headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
payload= {"postType":"Both","day":"Day1095","sort":"InsOrRegDate","order":"Descending","size":24,"offset":"24","pageSource":"search","gclid":"Cj0KCQjwnbmaBhD-ARIsAGTPcfVae1prjf_9aKh0dbnaBbzYvi3VhKn4qEXDAQJMS6ZvOiet8GLqzaAaAqH_EALw_wcB","q":"3qoOuFNgwUeioKQCtZ9KFA"}

lst = []
for p in range(0,240,24):
    payload['offset'] = p
    res=requests.post(api_url,headers=headers,json=payload)
   
    for item in res.json()['data']:
        d = {
            'flat':item['xAxis']
        }
        lst.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     flat
0     A室
1     B室
2     B室
3     2室
4     C室
..   ...
235   E室
236   F室
237   E室
238   8室
239   6室

[240 rows x 1 columns]
```